# Outlook Property Accessor error: The property "ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B" is unknown or cannot be found

Tags: outlook

I'm using the Outlook property accessor to email attachments.
This is the Code that I'm using:

```
 //check whether attachments are there or not
                            if (mailItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
                            {
                                //loop through all attachments
                                for (int j = 1; j <= mailItem.Attachments.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    //check if attachment is email attachment, then only save to local directory
                                    if (mailItem.Attachments[j].PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B") == false)
                                    {
                                        //save email attachment to local directory
                                        mailItem.Attachments[j].SaveAsFile
                                            (attachmentPath + "\\" +
                                            mailItem.Attachments[j].FileName);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

It's reading fine for most of the emails, but for a couple of them, I get this error:

> The property "ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B" is unknown or cannot be found.

I want to know what's the fix for this error and if there are any workarounds if the error is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the required property for attachments, i.e. not all attachments will have that property set.

The DASL property name corresponds to the [PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839828(v=office.15).aspx) property tag. It indicates whether an attachment is hidden from the end user.

Comment: Then how do i check if attachment has property or not?

Comment: The GetProperty method will fire an exception if a particular property doesn't exist. You need to use the try/catch blocks in the code.